How do I stop my custom kernel getting stuck on boot?
So, I built the Linux kernel, installed it and made the initramfs using mkinitcpio. I used update-grub and all looked nice, until when booting the kernel, it gets stuck on this screen:

Booting into my old not manually installed kernel from grub still works, so it's something to do with this one.
Also, the last message also occurs on my other (working) kernel, so I don't think it's the issue.
Edit: So I've gotten further down the debug process. If I add systemd.unit=multi-user.target to the boot parameters it does boot properly into the console, but running the 'sddm' command doesn't work, saying it can't find a display. I think it tries all my monitors and fails on all of them. Still working on it.

Have you compared your kernel configuration with the configuration used to build the working kernel?

Are you trying booting into a graphical environment?  If so, you might want to disable the graphical environment and see if the problem is a boot problem or something else (e.g., you might need to rebuild third-party graphic drivers for your new kernel).

@larsks no I haven't tried that, but I'm not sure how to since the config file isn't under /boot or /proc

oh never mind it is in proc, I'm just blind...

The problem was that there were no nvidia drivers, or maybe that it was trying to use old nvidia drivers for my old kernel, I'm not too sure. Either way, installing nvidia-dkms and having it build the drivers for my new kernel fixed it.
If you'd like more detail, what was happening was that sddm couldn't start because xorg was failing because the nvidia kernel module couldn't be loaded. If you get stuck on a similar screen, remember you can use ctrl + alt + F<Number> (where F<Number> is one of the function keys on your keyboard) to switch to a different terminal. Terminals 1 to 6 for me had 'getty' running, which allows you to login and run commands.
